# Email address encoding issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following string I need to use for a confirmation email 'from' address.  This is the spanish translation which is causing a problem when viewing within a web client.  Shown below.

```
model.FromAddresses = new EmailAddress
{
  Address = fromAddressComponents[0],
  DisplayName = fromAddressComponents[1]
};
```

Value taken from a resource string, shown below

```
  <data name="BookingConfirmation_FromAddress" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Confirmación@test.com</value>
  </data>
```

Within the email client the value becomes (should be Confirmación@test.com)

```
=?utf-8?Q?Confirmaci=C3=B3n
```

Can you see how to avoid this?  I know it's because of the ó but I'm not sure how to avoid this problem!

Thanks,
James

**UPDATE**

Full code below:

```
public void Send(MailAddress to, MailAddress from, string subject, string body)
    {
        var message = new MailMessage
                          {
                              BodyEncoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true),
                              From = from,
                              Subject = subject,
                              Body = body,
                              IsBodyHtml = true
                          };


        message.To.Add(to.Address);

        var smtp = new SmtpClient() { Timeout = 100000 };
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (smtp.DeliveryMethod == SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network)
                smtp.Dispose();
        }

    }





// New Version
// --------------------------


    public override void Handle(SendEmailEmailCommand emailCommand)
    {
        if(!_config.SendEmail)
        {
            return;
        }

        var to = new MailAddress(emailCommand.To.Address, emailCommand.To.DisplayName);
        var from = new MailAddress(emailCommand.From.Address, Uri.UnescapeDataString(emailCommand.From.DisplayName));

        try
        {
            var msgBody = _compressor.Decompress(emailCommand.Body);
            _emailClient.Send(to, from, emailCommand.Subject, msgBody);
        }       
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("An error occurred when trying to send an email", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }



    public void Send(MailAddress to, MailAddress from, string subject, string body)
    {
        var message = new MailMessage
                          {
                              BodyEncoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true),
                              From = from,
                              Subject = subject,
                              Body = body,
                              IsBodyHtml = true
                          };


        message.To.Add(to.Address);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_config.BccEmailRecipents))
        {
            message.Bcc.Add(_config.BccEmailRecipents);
        }


        SendEmail(message);

        if (_config.BackupEmailsEnabled)
        {
            SendBackupEmail(message);
        }
    }



    private void SendEmail(MailMessage message)
    {
        var smtp = new SmtpClient() { Timeout = 100000 };
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (smtp.DeliveryMethod == SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network)
                smtp.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but I tried ecncode/decode but it didn't work

Comment: Can you show the code how you are taking value from resource string???

Comment: Is that actually a valid e-mail address?

Comment: its the ó that causes the problem.. I'm viewing the email within the  Microsoft Outlook thin (browser) client.

Comment: Still you didnt paste the code from where the email id set to TO

Comment: @raman full listing above, if I'm stilling missing please state what you need!!! Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at this example below using [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class methods, hope it helps you

```
string email = "Confirmación@test.com";

string escaped = 
       System.Uri.EscapeDataString(email); // Confirmaci%C3%B3n%40test.com
string unescaped = 
       System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(email); //Confirmación@test.com
```

Comment: I get the following error message at run time (I've tried both EscapeDataString and UnescapeDataString): "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

Comment: @JamesRadford are you using it this way System.Uri.method(email);

Comment: please see my question update that includes where I'm using it.  If I use the escapeDataString method a runtime error happens saying the email address is invalid.  If I use the UnescapeDataString I receive the email successfully although with the incorrect characters for the DisplayName.

Comment: I spotted that in your new version you are not unescaping the To.Address in this line var to = new MailAddress(emailCommand.To.Address, emailCommand.To.DisplayName);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14330/discussion-between-james-radford-and-hatsoft)